# Which linear model should I use?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, linear

I have data collected from an experiment in which 24 subjects did the same task 4 times. So in total I have 96 data points. My research hypothesis is that there are always linear relationships between dependent variable Y and independent variable X regardless of time. I am thinking of two options.

1. Do 4 linear regressions and see if their p-values are all <.05 (or maybe <.0125 which is .05/4?).
2. Do 1 linear mixed effects model: Y ~ X + C(Run) + X*C(Run) (random effects = subject) and see if there is no interaction effect.

Which model should I use? Or can you recommend any other model?

Thank you in advance!

edit) Here is additional information.

Y = behavior score. The task was hard, so I wanted to see if people really learn how to do it rather than random act.

X = brain connectivity. So my research question, in specific, is that though people learn across Runs, those who have lower brain connectivity between brain region A and B always show the better behavior score. Since brain connectivity is calculated by pearson correlation, its range is between -1 and 1.

In addition, I added the visual result of the option 2 below.
[image]
[image]

If the option 2 is correct method, how do I know each line is significant? P values shown in the table (XC:C(Run)) are interaction effects, so I guess they mean that there are no interaction effect since all of their p-values are >.05. But I want to know each individual line itself is significant, since it seems run 2 and 4 are not significant...

Comment: What is the specific reason they did it four times?

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand It is because I wanted to see participants actually learned. So Y, behavior score, increases as time goes on.

Comment: But you said "regardless of time" in your post?!

Comment: @PatrickCoulombe So for example, for run 1, the range of Y is  1 - 2, and the range of X is 1-2 and there is a positive relationship. For run 2, the range of Y is 2 - 3 and the range of X is still 1 -2 and there is also a positive relationship, and so on and so forth. So there are 4 lines in parallel to some degree.

Comment: Andy, you give a lot of important information in your comments. Could you edit your question to include this information? Also what Y and X mean is helpful (Y=behavior score, x=?)

Comment: @Ute I did it. Thanks!

Comment: Andy, the plot looks nice but I have trouble interpreting it. What are the x- and y-axis? Did you normalize X and Y in each run such that the mean is 0?

Comment: @Ute X axis = brain connectivity between 2 brain regions (pearson correlation), Y = behavior score. And no, I didn't normalize it. I scatter plotted raw data.

Comment: But you wrote that the range of Y changes from run to run? 1-2, 2-3?

Comment: @Ute Yes! That's why intercepts are all significant. You can see Y values are hierarchical and the lines don't overlap much in terms of Y. At the early stage of learning (Run 1) blue dots locate in the bottom, whereas red dots (Run 4) position at top.

Comment: I was puzzled by the scale of the y values : 0.0 to 0.8, not 1-4. Would be interesting for you to see differences in learning speed (if there are any) depending on X? Or are X and Y rather outcomes of the same underlying cause?